# how do I get the title of a URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I have a URL and I will show the URL inside a ModalViewController. I would like to set the title of this URL in the navigation bar.

Inside the ModalViewController I have a UIWebView to display the site. Is there a way to extract the title of this site via UIWebView? Did a bit of research and it seems that I would like to use some javascript inside the  `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`
Not sure though how it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.title"];
    navbar.title = title;
}
```

Taken from: http://blog.mcohen.me/2008/12/12/getting-the-title-of-a-web-view-in-cocoa-touch/